# How to display single fields in multiple line in VIEWS?

Tags: views

How to display single fields in multiple line in view.

Example : Address contain multiple lines so each items show on line by line.

Comment: Use line break while user input and using regular expression `[^\n]+` break and string.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Views fields combine" Module